# Malformed Archived TOC Entry on creating StaticLib

Tags: c++, macos, linker

I'm currently working on a project which creates a static library and three executables that link to this library. On a clean build when I try to create the library on OSX 10.7.1 it will build correctly. However if it's not a clean build then I get this error.

```
ld: in ./libframework.a, malformed archive TOC entry for GameApp::~GameApp(), offset 222233108   is beyond end of file 3056 for architecture x86_64
```

Without changing any build settings if I do a clean build after receiving this error then it will compile without issues. The linking error doesn't seem to always apply to the same entry. If I comment out the desctructor then it will just refer to another entry.

Any ideas?

Comment: Some people work around this with
1. Turning off parallel build options in makefile
2. Running ranlib after ar and before ld (see last message in http://code.swtch.com/plan9port/issue/81/devdraw-does-not-build-on-os-x-lion-latest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error here is that the table of contents of the static library need to be updated when recompiling. To fix this the -s flag can be added to ar or ranlib can be executed after compiling the library but before linking.

Comment: On OSX 10.7.1 it appears as though the -s flag doesn't work despite what is written in the man pages.

Comment: Can you please explain more in detail how fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the issue by deleting the file (/Users/ios5/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/**/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/**.a)